# Meteor method callback is not fired after client simulation using ValidatedMethod

Tags: javascript, meteor, methods

I am using Meteor. As you can see in the README of ValidatedMethod on Github, it is using the returnStubValue option when calling a method, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I would like to know what you think about it.

**I've uploaded a simple Meteor project that reproduce the problem on Github** : [Link to the repository](https://github.com/damien-monni/validated-method-callback)

Here is my server side method:

```
export const createTodo = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'todos.create',
  validate: new SimpleSchema({
    todo: String,
  }).validator(),
  run({ todo }) {

    if (this.isSimulation) {
      return { finished: false };
    }

    Todos.insert({ todo });
    return { finished: true };
  },
});
```

This a simple method that insert a todo in a todos collection. On the client side I immediately return an object `{ finished: false }`. On the server side I update my database then return an object `{ finished: true }`

Here is my client side method call:

```
createTodo.call({ todo }, (err, res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

I just call the method and console.log the result. **Because I am using mdg:validated-method** which uses the `returnStubValue` option, I guess my console should output `finished: false`, then `finished: true`. But it actually only output `finished: true`.

Is there something I don't understand here?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Checking if `this.isSimulation` makes no sense, because of the entire body of your method _is_ simulation.

Comment: I want to indicate when a write to the server is in progress, using the exact same way as indicated in the Meteor guide : [just here](https://guide.meteor.com/ui-ux.html#writes-in-progress).
The body of my method is run server and client side, achieving [Optimistic UI](https://guide.meteor.com/ui-ux.html#optimistic-ui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mdg:validated-method` is doing fine. If you call (actually `Meteor.apply`) a regular Meteor method without introducing `validated-method`, the same result will be observed.

Here is the thing. In the [documentation](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html#call-lifecycle) of Meteor,

> The return value of the Method simulation is discarded, unless the
>   returnStubValue option is passed when calling the Method, in which
>   case it is **returned** to the Method caller. ValidatedMethod passes this
>   option by default.

Notice the bold. In your example project, the returned object `{ finished: false }` from simulation is the return value of the call, not the callback. Therefore, the following transformation of how you make the client call

```
const ret = createTodo.call({ todo }, (err, res) => {
  console.log('res', res);
});
console.log('ret', ret);
```

will print

```
ret, {finished, false}
res, {finished, true}
```

on the console. UI is made optimistic by waiting no server result. The behavior makes total sense, doesn't it?

Nice question!

Comment: You're right, awesome I finally understand it! Thank you.